# flexbox navigation w/ logo float & border-bottom issue

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-float, flexbox

Im trying to figure out how to add a logo to my flexbox navigation. I want the logo to float on the left. Also attempting to use the border-bottom on the link hover state, but it seems to be pushing the height of the bar down as well as having the entire li with a border instead of just the text.
any help pls!

```css
#nav {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #BF2B36;
}
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  background: #333333;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-family: 'BabasNeueBold';
  font-size:24px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  line-height:80px;
}

.logo {
  background:red;
 width:200px;
    height:50px;
 padding-top:10px;
  float:left;
}

.navigation a, .navigation a:active, .navigation a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}

.navigation a:hover {
 color: #BF2B36;
  border-bottom:2px solid #BF2B36;
}


@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navigation {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .navigation a { 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
  }
  
  .navigation a:hover {
 color: #BF2B36;
    border-bottom:2px solid #BF2B36;
}

  
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><div class="logo"></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no answer for the logo position just yet but the height issue is because you are adding a border of 2px only on hover. You could avoid this by adding a `border: 2px solid transparent` on the `a` in unhovered (default) state. You could also use an inset `box-shadow` instead of border to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using `flex-end` for aligning contents? It causes the items to sort of be aligned right and that seems to be why the logo is not aligning to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You just add  **border-bottom:2px solid transparent;**
for navigation a ...

```css
#nav {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #BF2B36;
}
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  background: #333333;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-family: 'BabasNeueBold';
  font-size:24px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  line-height:80px;
}

.logo {
  background:red;
 width:200px;
    height:50px;
 padding-top:10px;
  float:left;
}

.navigation a, .navigation a:active, .navigation a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing:2px;
 border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
}

.navigation a:hover {
 color: #BF2B36;
  border-bottom:2px solid #BF2B36;
}


@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navigation {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .navigation a { 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
  }
  
  .navigation a:hover {
 color: #BF2B36;
    border-bottom:2px solid #BF2B36;
}

  
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><div class="logo"></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```